# How do I import as float 64 in pandas?

Tags: pandas, floating-point

I have a dataset that I need to import a few columns as `float 64`, but when I try to import as `float 64` I get the following error in `pandas`:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4.131.460'
```

How would I remove all the . from the dataset and make it as a `flot64` not an object in pandas?

Comment: `.replace('.', '')` and then do `astype`???

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert to float because you have two 'dots' in your column numbers. I'm guessing that both dots are for marking the thousands and not the decimal. In this case, as suggested by [Pygirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6660373/pygirl), you can remove the dots to be able to convert to float.

```
df['your_col'].replace('.','', inplace=True)
```